# Attempting to install Realm 0.97.0

Tags: swift2, realm

When installing Realm in an xCode project it states.

> In your unit test target’s "Build Settings", add the parent path to
> RealmSwift.framework in the "Framework Search Paths" section.

I am not sure how exactly i do this. I have attempted to do this and thought i had done it but i think it is wrong. I have included an image below for you to see where i have added the path.

image of Xcode project
[image: image of Xcode project]

I'm not sure how to proceed until this is fixed.

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to add the path to the framework itself in the *Framework Search Paths*. You have to add the directory in which you have put it in your project directory.

Assuming you have the following project structure:

```
$ tree .
.
├── MyApp.xcodeproj
└── vendor
    └── RealmSwift.framework
```

That would mean you would need to add `$(SRCROOT)/vendor` to your Framework Search Paths.

Comment: Hi Marius, thanks for your reply. My app is called DogData and the frameworks appear to sit directly under that. So they appear to sit on the same level as the DogData Folder and Products Folder in my project. I'm guessing that means i only need to add the $(SRCROOT) to my paths, but that does't seem to work

Comment: The screen print suggests you are trying to do this in your project's build settings. However, this step is only required in your unit test target. If you don't have any unit tests, you don't need to do it.

Comment: "Expected Declaration"  appears on the line in which i attempt to declare a name variable within a new object. The is a link to screen shot http://we.tl/ybWT0EWgbZ

Comment: You've to write your code in a method. You can't just put code and method calls, which should be called at runtime into the class body.